# Output of one Task input to other Task

Tags: c#, multithreading, winforms

In Winforms, I have following: ProcessClientAsync adds an element to a ConcurrentDictionary. How can I ensure that the forloop runs after the Task.Run(). I tried to remove ConfigureAwait but it freezes the UI.

```
public async Task Listen(int port)
{
    try
  {
    IPAddress serverAddress = IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1"); // localhost

    _listener = new TcpListener(serverAddress, port);
    _listener.Start();

    while (true)
    {  
      TcpClient tcpClient = await _listener.AcceptTcpClientAsync();
      await Task.Run(() => ProcessTcpClientAsync(tcpClient).ConfigureAwait(false));
      _statusText.StatusUpdate = "number of users are " + _mapClient.GetUsers().Count;

    }
  }
  catch (SocketException ex)
  {
    string message = string.Format("Error listening on port {0}. Make sure IIS or another application is not running and consuming your port.", port);
    throw new Exception(message, ex);
  }
}

private async Task<string> ProcessTcpClientAsync(TcpClient tcpClient)
{
  string key = string.Empty;
  WebSocket webSocket = null;

  try
  {
    if (_isDisposed)
      return string.Empty;

    // this worker thread stays alive until either of the following happens:
    // Client sends a close conection request OR
    // An unhandled exception is thrown OR
    // The server is disposed

    // get a secure or insecure stream
    NetworkStream stream = tcpClient.GetStream();
    WebSocketHttpContext context = await _webSocketServerFactory.ReadHttpHeaderFromStreamAsync(stream);

    if (context.IsWebSocketRequest)
    {
      key = GetKeyFromContext(context);

      // _statusText.StatusUpdate = "Connection from origin.";
      webSocket = await _webSocketServerFactory.AcceptWebSocketAsync(context);

      //_statusText.StatusUpdate = "Connection accepted.";
      await RespondToWebSocketRequestAsync(tcpClient, key, webSocket);
    }
    else
    {
      //_statusText.StatusUpdate = "Http header contains no web socket upgrade request. Ignoring...";
    }
  }

  catch (Exception ex)
  {

  }
  finally
  {
    try
    {
      await webSocket.CloseOutputAsync(WebSocketCloseStatus.NormalClosure, "Closed in server by the client", CancellationToken.None);

      tcpClient.Client.Close();
      tcpClient.Close();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
    }
  }

  return key;
}
```

Comment: `await ProcessClientAsync(client);` is I think all you need

Comment: tried await also. it doesnt work.

Comment: @Gauravsa `await ProcessClientAsync(client);` *does* work. If it didn't, thousands of developers would have noticed 7 years ago. What did you try, what was the problem? What does  `ProcessClientAsync` do? If it returns anything you should use `var result=await ProcessClientAsync(client);`. If *not*, you should use `await ProcessClientAsync(client)` and ensure whatever side-effects it has are thread-safe. Needless to say, it's better to return results than modify global state or have other side effects

Comment: Are you sure `ProcessClientAsync` works to begin with? What is its signature, code? If it's `async void` you have a bug. `async void` is only meant for event handlers as you can't await such methods

Comment: The way the code is right now *guarantees* that the global dictionary will be empy for the first iterations. Worse, the loop will keep firing off tasks that try to do whatever that method does and modify the global dictionary. You may have fired off 1000 tasks in 1 millisecond

Comment: Finally `.ConfigureAwait(false)` plays no role at all since you don't *await* anything

Comment: ok. i updated the code. added ProcessClientAsync

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could await the *Task.Run*, but make sure to make the parent method *async*

```
await Task.Run(() => ProcessClientAsync(client).ConfigureAwait(false));
```

This will wait for the async task to complete, and then execute the rest of the code. I would suggest learning a bit more about async/await.

Answer (score 1):

To block the ProcessClientAsync call you can do the following:

```
Task.Run(() => ProcessClientAsync(client)).Wait();
```

If you want to access the result of ProcessClientAsync:

```
Task<TResult> task = null;
Task.Run(() => task = ProcessClientAsync(client)).Wait();

// task.Result contains the result
```

Even if this works, it's recommended to await tasks rather than blocking with wait.

Answer (score 1):

Quiz, what is the type of the variable `x` below?

```
var x = Task.Run(() => Task.Delay(1000).ConfigureAwait(false));
```

The type is not `Task`. It is `Task<ConfiguredTaskAwaitable>`. That internal `ConfigureAwait(false)` call is not only meaningless, but it also created a
unexpected situation where the return value must now be awaited twice:

```
await await x;
```

Don't do this. If you have to use `ConfigureAwait(false)` for some reason, then you are expected to `await` the result immediately. Don't pass [`ConfiguredTaskAwaitable`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.compilerservices.configuredtaskawaitable) structs around. My advice is to search your code for more instances of this anti-pattern, and eliminate them.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to mark the parent method as async, then you could use the following instead:

```
Task.Wait(Task.Run(() => ProcessClientAsync(client)));
```

This method has several overloads that allow for configurability of cancellation and timeouts as well:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.wait?view=netframework-4.8

Also, if your code actually says `while (true)` and has no break conditions, then it will never exit.

Comment: Can you edit your question to show what the processClientAsync method does?

Comment: Also, do you actually have a while (true) loop? If so this will never exit

Comment: This is a server. It keeps listening for clients. It processes the clients on a separate task

Comment: added ProcessClientAsync